# Loop or function for sequence of matrices of sst data

Tags: r

I have been looking for a way to select the frequency of values within a range in R from a sequence of matrices of sea surface temperature (sst) by month. These data are arranged as (sst, 80*40*172) i.e., (sst, longitude,latitude, month) for the north Atlantic. I'am interested in those frequencies because I use them to calculate the surface area of a range in sst for every month say between 4°C and 12°C isotherms. I have used R frequently for statistical analyses of time-series and spatial data, but I'am not used to programming so my approach is probably not the most efficient. I have succeeded in extracting  frequencies for sst values of say >12 °C for a all latitudes in one month:

My data from IRI/LDEO climate research web site

```
dat <- read.table("c:/Temp/[Y+X]datatable.tsv", header=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

A 5x5 sample matrix of the first month

```
    Nov 1981    30.5000 31.5000 32.5000 33.5000
    9.50000     21.7906 21.9431 22.1324 22.1662
    8.50000     21.7267 21.8573 21.9981 21.8757
    7.50000     21.6644 21.7781 21.8960 21.7393
    6.50000     21.5989 21.7025 21.8044 21.6304
```

I basically skip the longitude, row labels I also intend to add the date latter. First I extract the first month as a matrix (t) and apply two custom functions surface area of 
lat strip SA and surface area of all lat strips for the month MSA.

```
ro=2:81
co=2:41
t <- as.matrix(dat[ro,co])
```

Then

```
SA <- function (lat,tmu){
    l <- c(t[,lat]>=tmu,0)
    la <- as.data.frame(l)
    x  <- la[,1] 
    n  <- length(x)
    sau <- array(0,n)
    x. <- lat
    for (i in 1:n) sau[i] <- (x[i]*111.320)*(cos(x.*(3.1415/180))*111.320)
    s <- as.matrix(sum(sau))
}
MSA <- function(tmu){
    m <-1:40
    su <- array(0,0)
    for (i in 1:40) su[i] <-SA(m[i],tmu)
    ms <- as.data.frame(su)
    sa <- as.data.frame(colSums (ms))
    return(sa)
}
```

Functions SA and MSA  or surface area an surface of one latitude (lat) strip SA and area of all strips for the month SAM, for temperature upper limit (tmu).

Matrix (s) from function SA has the surface area of sst> tmu(say 12 °C) for latitude(lat)(say at 30°N) and Matrix (sa) from function SAM has the sums of all the latitudes (from 30°N to 70°N).This does the job for one month and I can repeat the functions 12 times to obtain the year or 172 times for the 16 years this way:

I define a starting latitude (lat) then a step of 81 longitude cells (st) to extract next and the desired temperature;

```
lat= 30.5 
st=81 
t=12
```

Then calculate the total surface area for each month;

```
SA1 <- {
    i=0*st 
    t <- as.matrix(dat[ro+i,co])
    SA(lat,t)
    MSA(12)
}

SA2 <- {
    i=1*st 
    t <- as.matrix(dat[ro+i,co])
    SA(30.5,t)
    MSA(12)
}
```

My question is if it is possible to create a loop or a function that would iterate through all  months that is 172 times and so skip repeating SA1,SA2...SA172. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify which dataset do you use ?

Comment: How are the month/ years organized in your data set? Can you put them all into an array e.g: `fullData=array(0,dim=c(80,40,12,16)` and then fill it?

Comment: Sorry Alan (stackoverflow.com/users/1529381/alan), I didn't notice your comment. These data are sea surface temperatures (SST) from the Reyn_SmithOIv2 data set.

Comment: Hello (stackoverflow.com/users/1474724/discretecircle) . A utility in the IRI/LDEO wweb page (http://iridl.ldeo.columbia.edu/)delivers the data in various formats (ncdf,hdf or as DODs link to FERRET or GRads or Matlab toolboxes from climate data. I chose to get it as an array of monthy values as shown above, this request starts in Nov 1981 with lats. as colums and longs. as rows and has 172 steps i.e., 12 yrs of data. I will try to put them into an array as you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, your code reduces to this

```
#create some dummy data
lat <- 30:33
lon <- 6:9
sst <- array(rnorm(length(lat) * length(lon) * 12, mean = 21, sd = 4), 
    dim = c(length(lat), length(lon), 12), dimnames = list(lat, lon, 1:12))
#the actual code
SA <- function (test, tmu){
  colSums(test >= tmu) * 111.320 ^ 2 * 
     cos(as.numeric(rownames(test)) * (pi/180))
}
apply(sst, 3, SA, tmu = 21)
```

If this is not correct, please make your question more clear and provide a [reproducible](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Reproducibility) input and output dataset.

Comment: Thaks very much Thierry, I will see how it works for me otherwise I will do as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks again Thierry, it seems it was all down to knowing the way R handles rows an columns. Your code is neat an does exactly what I needed, only that you flipped lat-long, but that was easy to fix.